# Nested DIVs and horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I Have the follow DIVs:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>Box 1</div>
    <div>Box 2</div>
    <div>Box 3</div>
</div>
```

And the follow CSS:

```
.container{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:gray;
    overflow: auto;
}

.container div{
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

That returns this result:
http://jsfiddle.net/becy1x62/

I want a horizontal scrollbar and not the vertical one. I don know why the DIVs inside the container are breaking line.

Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set a width of 200px on the container. This forces wrapping. To prevent that, use the `white-space` property:

```
.container {
    ...
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/becy1x62/1/)**